# How to customize login page of Acumatica

Tags: cloud, customization, erp, acumatica

Can anyone guide me how to customize login page in Acumatica? I want to add some information when choosing company to login.
Thanks for your supporting.

Comment: Hm. Tell me please which build of Acumatica do you use? I can try to install at my computer your build and hopefully will give you some kind of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my trick

First modify your Frames/Login.aspx.cs and add the following function

```
    private DataSet GetCompanyList()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectX"].ConnectionString;
        string queryString = "SELECT b.AcctCD, b.AcctName FROM BAccount b WHERE b.[Type] = 'CP'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString);

        DataSet companies = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(companies, "BAccount");

        return companies;
    }
```

Then edit FillCompanyCombo function:

```
private void FillCompanyCombo()
{
    DataSet ds = GetCompanyList();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    string[] companies = PXDatabase.AvailableCompanies;

    var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                join a in companies on row["AcctCD"].ToString().Trim() equals a
                select new { Code = a, Name = row["AcctName"] };
    var list = query.ToList();

    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        this.cmbCompany.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.cmbCompany.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            this.cmbCompany.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Code + " - " + item.Name, item.Code));
        }

        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            this.cmbCompany.Visible = false;
            this.cmbCompany.SelectedValue = this.cmbCompany.Items[0].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = this.Request.Cookies["CompanyID"];
            if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
                this.cmbCompany.SelectedValue = cookie.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As proposal where to look I can propose you to analyze page MasterPages\Login.master and modify there some information.

Comment: I am working with acumatica version 4.0 so I cannot find Login.master.